# Why wont unlink() work with .htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, unlink

Maybe a daft question but I cant seem to find an answer anywhere. Does unlink() work on .htaccess files? I want to delete .htaccess but it doesnt work using unlink().

Perhaps some clarity:

I have a profile system set up on my application where users have a profile folder using .htaccess for various reasons. If an administrator of the application wants to delete a user then I want to delete the profile folder as well as the account. I have it all working except for the removal of the .htaccess file. So it is not my code that is wrong, it just doesnt seem to read the .htaccess file as a file, if you see what I mean?

This is the code I am using (each folder has an htaccess file in it):

```
        $dir = "../Profiles/".$course."/$student";

    if(is_dir($dir)){

        function recursiveRemoveDirectory($directory) {

            foreach(glob("{$directory}/*") as $file) {

                echo $file."<br><br>";

                if(is_dir($file)) { 

                    recursiveRemoveDirectory($file);

                } else {

                    //Delete the file
                    unlink($file);

                }

            }
              rmdir($directory);  
        }

        recursiveRemoveDirectory($dir);

    } else {
        echo $student." does not have a directory to remove";
    }

    if(!rmdir($dir)){
        echo "Unable to delete ".$student;
    } else {
        echo $student." has been deleted.";
    }
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#68869

Comment: A simple link as you have done would have sufficed. No need to mark down.

Comment: Perhaps you could have been extra helpful and provided a solution as to how I could incorporate that into my code?

Comment: I'm throwing a rock in the pond here, but have you checked that PHP is actually allowed to remove `.htaccess` files? I would not be surprised if it was not possible (at least by default) for security purposes.

Comment: Yes, I wondered that myself but I cant find anything online that helps

Comment: @NoahBoegli glob does not _read_ the file from the directory to begin with here (see first comment), so not even an _attempt_ to delete it will be made.

Comment: @CBroe I'm not sure I understand the tone of your comment? I was not commenting on your link (otherwise I would have mentioned you). I commented this because I found strange that `unlink` deleted all the files except for the `.htaccess` so it's either a permission issue or an issue with files with a `.` at the beginning of the name.

Comment: @NoahBoegli `glob('*')` does not return any files with names starting with a dot to begin with. So this script in the current form will never _attempt_ to delete any `.htaccess` file in the first place. And given that, I don’t see much point in discussing any potential file access issues at this point - no one has attempted any access of that file so far. I think this just leads in a wrong direction here.

Comment: @CBroe - it would have been nice if you had explained how I could have incorporated the info from the link you kindly provided into my code. Do not simply assume that anyone could understand how to do it. This forum is to help, not to dismiss. I understand what you are saying, however as I am not completely savvy with php I cannot figure out how to adapt it. This is where people like you come in. All you are doing is coming across, Im sorry, quite rude and arrogant and not helping to provide a solution to the problem you have correctly identified.

Comment: Yes, but you could also at least make an _attempt_ first, that would be nice as well. Show us what you tried, explain what happend, then we are happy to help with the details. // In this case, the comment in the manual explained why `glob('*')` did not work, and replaces it with `glob('{,.}*', GLOB_BRACE)`. You had `glob("{$directory}/*")` to begin with, so that should be something like `glob("{$directory}/{,.}*", GLOB_BRACE)` then.

Comment: ATTENTION, as the comment explains, this also gets you the entries `.` and `..`, which point to the current and parent directory, respectively. You need to exclude/skip those in your loop - if you call the function recursively again with `..`, then it will probably start deleting _parent_ directories, and probably eat its way “up” until it reaches a point where it doesn’t have the file system permission to delete stuff any more.

Comment: Thank you, this is much more helpful. I did actually try the suggested solution on the link you provided however it would have attempted to remove a lot more than just the files and folders I wanted, as you stated. Luckily I did it in a testing environment. Thank you for you help.